# How to go back to the default GUI?

Tags: gui, plasma, default

I installed KDE-Plasma GUI and I didn't like it. Now I want to go back to the default GUI as if I never installed Plasma.

Comment: I run Xubuntu and recently I installed Kubuntu (KDE Plasma).  Well, the Plasma messed up my Xubuntu theming to the point that I couldn't restore it back to defaults.  Plus, apps from KDE were installed and not removed by default when I removed the Kubuntu installation.  I ended up backing up what I had in my home folder and anything that I cannot afford to lose and wiped out and cleanly installed my Xubuntu (Xfce4) again.

Comment: Thank you! There should be a simpler way but I guess every os has it's flaws. Fortunately I don't use Linux as my main os as I have a dual boot (win/linux).

Comment: *"There should be a simpler way"* -- Yes there is.  It's to use the flavor of Ubuntu that has the DE that you want.  There's a very good reason why they are distributed separately even though they are all the same OS (Ubuntu)-- switching out a DE involves swapping out dozens and dozens of packages, and for the packages that *aren't* swapped out, many handle config files differently.  In the future if you just want to try out a different DE, then you should use the "Try Ubuntu" option from installation media, so it won't wreck your installed system.